# Preventing code repeatation in JSF

Tags: jsf, optimization, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi guys i am wondering if there is a solution to my problem

basically i am using a section of code repeated in over 10 pages, and instead of just copying and pasting the code i am wondering if i can store this in a template file and call it each time i need to use it to prevent the code being repeated on all pages. Only thing is i need to change the value for `<p:tooltip` sections on every page

this is the code i am looking to add to a master file and use constantly app

```
                    <p:column>  
                        <br></br>
                        <p:selectOneRadio id="radioButtons" value="#{formBean.number}" layout="grid" columns="1"   required = "True"
                                          requiredMessage="#{bundle.messageSelectMarkRange}" > 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="0 - 19" itemValue="1" /> 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="20 - 39" itemValue="2" />  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="40 - 49 " itemValue="4" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="50 - 59" itemValue="5" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="60 - 69" itemValue="6" />  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="70 - 79" itemValue="7" />  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="80 - 100" itemValue="8" />  
                            <p:ajax process="@this" update="mySpinnerPanel" />
                        </p:selectOneRadio>  
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p>
                            <p:button id="help0-19" icon="ui-icon-help">                           
                            </p:button>   
                            <p:tooltip for="help0-19" value="No statement or very generalised with vague aims or objectives" 
                                       showEffect="clip" hideEffect="explode" /> 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <p:button id="help20-39" icon="ui-icon-help">                           
                            </p:button>   
                            <p:tooltip for="help20-39" value="No statement or very generalised with vague aims or objectives" 
                                       showEffect="clip" hideEffect="explode" /> 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <p:button id="help40-49" icon="ui-icon-help">                           
                            </p:button>   
                            <p:tooltip for="help40-49" value="Problem topic and aims and objectives apparent Shows limited understanding and analysis" 
                                       showEffect="clip" hideEffect="explode" /> 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <p:button id="help50-59" icon="ui-icon-help">                           
                            </p:button>   
                            <p:tooltip for="help50-59" value="Problem topic and aims and objectives well presented, showing understanding and analysis. Key aspects of the context are covered"
                                       showEffect="clip" hideEffect="explode" /> 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <p:button id="help60-69" icon="ui-icon-help">                           
                            </p:button>   
                            <p:tooltip for="help60-69" value="Problem topic and aims and objectives well framed and viewed in wider context"
                                       showEffect="clip" hideEffect="explode" /> 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <p:button id="help70-79" icon="ui-icon-help">                           
                            </p:button>   
                            <p:tooltip for="help70-79" value="Problem is clearly shown to be challenging or shows originality and confidence in criticising assumptions"
                                       showEffect="clip" hideEffect="explode" /> 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <p:button id="help80-100" icon="ui-icon-help">                           
                            </p:button>   
                            <p:tooltip for="help80-100" value="Analysis of problem adds new insights"
                                       showEffect="clip" hideEffect="explode" /> 
                        </p>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputPanel id = "mySpinnerPanel" layout ="pageDirection">    
                            <!-- look into validation for this to prevent any unwanted values, better than the min max etc -->
                            <p>
                                <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner0-19" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}" 
                                           stepFactor = "1"  min="0" max="19" 
                                           disabled = "#{formBean.number != 1}" >  
                                    <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue " process="@this" />  
                                </p:spinner> 

                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner20-39" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}" 
                                           stepFactor = "1"  min="20" max="39" disabled = "#{formBean.number != 2}">  
                                    <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />  
                                </p:spinner> 

                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner40-49" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}" 
                                           stepFactor = "1"  min="40" max="49"  disabled = "#{formBean.number != 4}">  
                                    <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />  
                                </p:spinner> 

                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner50-59" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}" 
                                           stepFactor = "1"  min="50" max="59" disabled = "#{formBean.number != 5}">  
                                    <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />  
                                </p:spinner> 

                            </p>            
                            <p>
                                <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner60-69" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}" 
                                           stepFactor = "1"  min="60" max="69" disabled = "#{formBean.number != 6}">  
                                    <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />  
                                </p:spinner> 

                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner70-79" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}" 
                                           stepFactor = "1"  min="70" max="79" disabled = "#{formBean.number != 7}">  
                                    <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />  
                                </p:spinner> 
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <!--
                                     This acts as markingBean.getMarkSectionOne.getSpinnerField() when rendering
                             and as markingBean.getMarkSectionOne.setSpinnerField(spinner.getValue()) when sending the request to the server
                                -->
                                <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner80-100" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}"
                                           stepFactor="1"  min="80" max="100" disabled="#{formBean.number != 8}">
                                    <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />
                                </p:spinner>
                            </p>
                        </p:outputPanel>  
                    </p:column>

                    <f:facet name="footer">  
                        Total mark for this section is:
                        <h:outputText id="ajaxspinnervalue" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}" /> 
                    </f:facet>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p>
            <!-- testing to make sure the correct value is passed  --> 
            <p>
                <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.buttonNextSection}"  icon ="ui-icon-disk" update="displayMark :growl" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" /> 
            </p>
            <p:dialog header="Confirm Mark" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fold" hideEffect="fold">  
                <h:panelGrid id="displayMark" columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
                    <h:outputText value="Mark to be submitted: " />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}" />  
                    <p:commandButton id="save"
                                     value="#{bundle.buttonSave}"
                                     actionListener ="#{markingBean.editMark}"
                                     update=":growl"
                                     icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
                </h:panelGrid>  
            </p:dialog>
```

and the only section of code that will need changing is on each of the `p:button` is the `p:tootip` value

is this possible ? as i think it would streamline the app a lot, espcially the generation of new pages

Comment: Do you want to include this code only once per page ? Else, you're going to have to deal with component ids to..

Comment: Yep the code is only displayed once per page, but is shown on 10 pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `<ui:include>` . Move your repeaded html code in a file named, say, commonForm.xhml. it should look like this

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<p:column>
    <br></br>
    <p:selectOneRadio id="radioButtons" value="#{formBean.number}"
        layout="grid" columns="1" required="True"

    .......

        <p:button id="help20-39" icon="ui-icon-help">
        </p:button>
        <p:tooltip for="#{tooltipBean.tooltip20_30}"
            ....
```

Notice that the tooltip fethces it's text from a new Bean, I called TooltipBean.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TooltipBean implements Serializable {

private String tooltip20_30;

public String getTooltip20_30() {
    return tooltip20_30;
}

public void setTooltip20_30(String tooltip20_30) {
    this.tooltip20_30 = tooltip20_30;
}

public void setupForPageA(){
    tooltip20_30 = "No statement or very generalised with vague aims or objectives";
}

public void setupForPageB(){
    tooltip20_30 = "All Your Base are Belong to us";
}
```

You can set tooltipBean differently in every xhtml page you want to include your common form

for example, you can include it in pageA.xhtml like this:

```
<f:event listener="#{tooltipBean.setupForPageA}" type="preRenderView" />    
...
<ui:include src="../common/commonForm.xhtml"/>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, this makes sense, i will try it out shortly